# JavaScript: How to replace code within element without innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, appendchild, removechild

I want to replace content within element in JavaScript but I cannot use **innerHTML** and **jQuery**.

For example:

```
<div id="MyID">
<b>Hi,</b> how are you?<br/>
I am fine.
</div>
```

I want to replace everything between `<div id="MyID">` and `</div>`.

Like via innerHTML which I sadly cannot use:

```
document.getElementById('MyID').innerHTML = document.getElementById('MyID').innerHTML.replace(/you/, '<a href="">you</a>');
```

Which will be:

```
<div id="MyID">
<b>Hi,</b> how are <a href="">you</a>?<br/>
I am fine.
</div>
```

How to do it?

I tried things like **appendChild** and **removeChild** but I still cannot figure it out.

Comment: I have no idea why you would be restricted with not using `innerHTML` and `jQuery` but that tells me enough to know that you should get a SPA framework.

Answer (score 0):

For appendChild, you should append a dom entity

Answer (score 0):

Use remove() to clear the existing content and then insertAdjacentHTML() to enter the new content. Here is your code sample as an example.

```
<div id="MyID">
<span id="MyID2">
<b>Hi,</b> how are you?<br/>
I am fine.
</span>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Insert a paragraph</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var a = document.getElementById("MyID2");
a.remove();
var b = document.getElementById("MyID");
b.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<b>Hi,</b> how are <a href="">you</a>?<br/>I am fine.');
}
</script>
```